# How to enable SDO in WAMP Server

Tags: php, sdo

I want to enable SDO to use SDO_DAS_XML but I'm getting the error "Class 'SDO_DAS_XML' not found". I am using WAMP Server and dont see any setting for it under PHP Settings or PHP Extensions. Please help

Answer (score 0):

This extension is pretty much abandoned, so I wouldn't recommend using it But,

First install the SDO package.

for Linux:

see this [dosc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/sdo.installation.php) for install and edit `php.ini`:

```
extension=sdo.so
extension=sdo_das_xml.so
```

For Windows:

you need to [download](http://originaldll.com/file/php_sdo.dll/32050.html) `sdo.dll` file extansion and install with this [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.windows.php) and edit `php.ini`:

```
extension=php_sdo.dll
extension=php_sdo_das_xml.dll
```

Comment: I was just typing the same thing. **But** the download link for php_sdo.dll is no longer working. (It is the one you can find all over the internet) So please provide a working version of php_sdo.dll for him, if you can... (other than version 5.2.6.6 which probably won't work in the latest Wamp-installation)

Comment: @Rik: `php` version is?

Comment: My WampServer is 2.4 and has PHP version 5.4.16. This gives `PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: sdo: Unable to initialize module Module compiled with module API=20060613. PHP compiled with module API=20100525. These options need to match.`. Perhaps @Indy can download an old version of WampServer and use php_sdo.dll v.5.2.6.6 which floats around the internet. That version is from 2008 so it's pretty old and he would have to go to a very early version of WampServer (if it exists at all).

Comment: check This [link](http://t1522.php-sca-sdo.phptalks.us/installation-of-php-sdo-sca-for-php-5-3-t1522.html) and this [source](https://github.com/CloCkWeRX/sdo) for Install sdo for PHP 5.3+.

Answer (score 0):

You will need the SDO package. Unfortunately this package is no longer being maintained and won't compile on Linux and Windows.

You can't just load the existing extension of an earlier version in a newer PHP version (which comes with WampServer).

The latest version of WampServer i could find with the extension php_sdo.dll included is version 5.1.7.4. You can find it [here with the outdated WampServer downloads](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/files/WampServer%20OutDated/WAMP5/). You can use the top one (WAMP5 1.7.4).

If you use that version of WampServer you can use the menu of WampServer to enable php_sdo in the PHP-extensions. (You will need to uninstall your current WampServer and its services)